# How to add x2 to the right of a matrix

Tags: beamer

I am drawing a matrix and I want to show that one of the rows has been selected twice.  I have highlighted the row in blue but I would like to add `\times 2` (which looks like "x2") just to the right of the blue highlighted row outside of the bracket. How can I do that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{equation*}
M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
M_{0,0} & M_{0,1} & M_{0,2} \\ 
\rowcolor{red!20}
M_{1,0} & M_{1,1} & M_{1,2} \\ 
M_{2,0} & M_{2,1} & M_{2,2} \\ 
M_{3,0} & M_{3,1} & M_{3,2} \\
\rowcolor{green!20} 
M_{4,0} & M_{4,1} & M_{4,2} \\ 
M_{5,0} & M_{5,1} & M_{5,2} \\ 
\rowcolor{blue!20}
M_{6,0} & M_{6,1} & M_{6,2} \\ 
M_{7,0} & M_{7,1} & M_{7,2} \\ 
M_{8,0} & M_{8,1} & M_{8,2} \\ 
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the “times 2” as a zero width box:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{equation*}
M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
M_{0,0} & M_{0,1} & M_{0,2} \\ 
\rowcolor{red!20}
M_{1,0} & M_{1,1} & M_{1,2} \\ 
M_{2,0} & M_{2,1} & M_{2,2} \\ 
M_{3,0} & M_{3,1} & M_{3,2} \\
\rowcolor{green!20} 
M_{4,0} & M_{4,1} & M_{4,2} \\ 
M_{5,0} & M_{5,1} & M_{5,2} \\ 
\rowcolor{blue!20}
M_{6,0} & M_{6,1} & M_{6,2}\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1.2em}$\scriptstyle{}\times 2$} \\ 
M_{7,0} & M_{7,1} & M_{7,2} \\ 
M_{8,0} & M_{8,1} & M_{8,2} \\ 
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very impressive thank you!   I would never have guessed you could put $\times 2$ outside the bracket by adding it to a row inside the bracket.

Comment: @Lembik If you need to place objects next to this matrix, pay attention that the added box takes no horizontal space; if it is alone in a display, there is no problem (although the added label doesn't count for the centering).